# Error `is not defined` in python programming

Tags: python

I have a recurring error in my code:

```
line 424, in <module>
menu() line 50, in menu
main1v1() line 396, in main1v1
showPoints(playerTile, opponentTile)
line 307, in showPoints
scores = getScoreOfBoard(mainBoard)
NameError: name 'mainBoard' is not defined
```

I cannot seem to fix it.
These two definitions are where the trouble is I believe.
I am currently coding for a game called Othello, but now when I am trying to create a 1v1 instead of the previous 1vAI it creates some problems.

Comment: could you post the full error stacktrace?

Comment: check new update

Comment: Please do not update your question in such a way. Ask a new question instead. We don't want problems to be concealed once solved; that's not the point of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `showPoints1v1` uses variable `mainBoard` but it is neither defined inside that, nor is an argument. You need to define it or pass it as an argument while calling it.

Comment: oh ty, so you mean I just add it as an argument in the `def showPoints1v1(playerTile, opponentTile, mainBoard`

Comment: Yes. That the way if you want to use mainBoard inside your showPoints1v1 function.

Comment: Or use `global`, even though I personally don't like it